# Ruby: Read from PTY master_io hangs

Tags: ruby, pty

I'm using Ruby and I have the following code for ssh-ing into a router and running a series of commands that are stored in an arrary:

```rb
result = PTY.open do |masterIO, slaveFile|
    r, w = IO.pipe

    slaveFile.raw!    
    pid = spawn(sshCommand, :in=>r, :out=>slaveFile)
    r.close; slaveFile.close;

    output = ""
    @commands.each do |subCommand|
        w.puts subCommand
        masterIO.each_line { |line| output += line }
    end
    next ouput
end
```

My problem is that `masterIO.each_line { ... }` hangs forever. In the code above, I think I need to close `w` but I'm still not sure how to write this to get it to behave like I want.

**Note:** You have to keep in mind that the subCommands aren't instant, so I need some way of waiting until the first command is finished executing before I write the second command.

**EDIT :**

I guess I could just concat all the commands with '&&' between each.  That would allow me to run them sequentially, but I'm still not sure how to make reading the output of those commands work successfully

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't use net/ssh lib?

```
require 'net/ssh'

Net::SSH.start('ip', 'user', password: 'your_password') do |ssh|
  @commands.each {|command| ssh.exec(command)}
end
```

Comment: I didn't know it existed and I didn't think to look (: